# Default radio button with scope in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, scope, radio-button

What is the best way I can make `One-Shot` the default radio button selection?

**_form**

```
<% Challenge::CATEGORY.each do |c| %>&nbsp;
  <span class="label label-primary"> <%= label(c, c) %> </span>
  <%= f.radio_button(:category, c, :class => "date-format-switcher") %>
<% end %>

<div id='id_of_first_div'>
  One-Shot
</div>

<div id='id_of_second_div'>
  Ongoing
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
  $('#challenge_category_one-shot').click(function(){ $('#id_of_first_div').show(); $('#id_of_second_div').hide(); });
  $('#challenge_category_ongoing').click(function(){ $('#id_of_first_div').hide(); $('#id_of_second_div').show(); });
});
</script>
```

**challenge.rb**

```
scope :oneshot,  -> { where(categories: 'One-Shot') }
scope :ongoing,  -> { where(categories: 'Ongoing') }
CATEGORY = ['One-Shot', 'Ongoing']
```

**schema**

```
t.string   "category"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intent on using f.radio_button then you could add the parameter

```
checked: (c=='One-Shot')
```

You could also use r.collection_radio_buttons instead:

```
<% categories = ['One-Shot', 'Ongoing'] %>                                    
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :category, categories, :to_s, :to_s, {checked: 'One-Shot'} %>
```

Comment: Thanks again! I tried both your solutions, which work great at setting the default to `One-Shot` but the solutions create a problem with the last question I posted that you helped me with :] which is that when the page is loaded both are still shown: `<div id='id_of_first_div'>` and `<div id='id_of_second_div'>` instead of just showing `<div id='id_of_first_div'>`, which is correlated with `One-Shot`. You know what I mean? I can post a new question if you'd prefer

Comment: Add another $('#id_of_div_you_want_to_hide').hide() into the onready function (`$(function(){ ... }`).